# MySQL SELECT WHERE id IN() get num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code to show category from database

```
$select_newscats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news_cats order by ord_show asc");

while ($rows_newscats = $select_newscats->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_newscats          = $rows_newscats ['id'];
$title_newscats       = $rows_newscats ['title'];
$ord_show_newscats    = $rows_newscats ['ord_show'];
$icon_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['icon'];
$kind_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['kind'];
$description_newscats = $rows_newscats ['description'];

//here is my data

}
```

i have in news table row for categoies it's name is cats and i insert data inside it like that `1,5,6,8`

and i use this code to count news inside each cat

```
$select_newsnum = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM news where $id_newscats  IN (cats)");
$rows_newsnum   = $select_newsnum->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
$num_newsnum    = $select_newsnum->num_rows;
```

it gets only first value for example if i have this values `1,5,6,8` it gets only `1` the first value

Comment: You have to fetch once and loop on "$rows_newscats", not fetching in a loop

Answer (score 1):

I would do the counting in a single sql call, not with php logic and separate sql calls. For this I would join the 2 tables using left join and use a join condition instead of an `in` clause:

```
SELECT nc.id, nc.title, nc.ord_show, nc.icon, nc.king, nc.description, count(n.id) as newsnum
FROM news_cats nc
LEFT JOIN news n ON nc.id=n.cats
GROUP BY nc.id, nc.title, nc.ord_show, nc.icon, nc.king, nc.description
ORDER BY nc.ord_show asc
```

Obviously, make sure that the join condition is the right one. When you loop through the resultset, the number of news per category will be in the `newsnum` field.

Comment: it has the same problem it gets only first value

Comment: I'm sorry, but then you do not loop through the results of this query. There is no limitation in the query to return only the 1st number. Try it out in your favourite mysql management app! My query should replace `SELECT * FROM news_cats order by ord_show asc` query at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_newsnum = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM news where $id_newscats  IN (cats)");
$rows_newsnum   = $select_newsnum->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
$num_newsnum    = $select_newsnum->num_rows;
```

Here $rows_newsnum will only return the first row in the database.

Fetch Array only returns one row at a time, and then moves the row pointer forward. For example the following code on the dataset you provided (1, 5, 6, 8).

```
$rows_newsnum = $select_newsnum->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $rows_newsnum["id"]; // Will print 1
$rows_newsnum = $select_newsnum->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $rows_newsnum["id"]; // Will print 5
```

What you need to do is move it into a while loop (like your first example) to get to access each row, like below:

```
while($row = $select_newsnum->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $rows_newsnum["id"] . ", ";
}

// Will produce:
// 1, 5, 6, 8,
```

**If you just want to get a count**

Your existing code should work fine. And you can omit the call to fetch_array.

```
$num_newsnum = $select_newsnum->num_rows;
echo $num_newsnum; // Will display 4
```

Read more about fetch_array on the PHP documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Hope this helps.